# How to get rid of this IE message "Internet Explorer can not display the webpage"?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, html, javascript

Whenever I access my website (http://www.martani.net) in Internet Explorer 7 it shows me the following message:

> Internet Explorer can not display the webpage 
>   operation abandoned

[image]

The website almost loads completely, but at the end it shows this message and it turns to its default error page:

[image]

The website works normally in the other browsers. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the URL

Comment: Also what's the information in the Informations section - that will give more details about the error causing the page to fail to display.

Comment: I like the tag line of your blog: "If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts. (Albert Einstein)"

Answer (score 2):

I pulled up your site and got an error that refers to the following Microsoft KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917

It seems to be the error you're talking about, and it has info on how to correct it from both the user and developer end.

Comment: "The easiest way for you to fix the problem is to upgrade to Internet Explorer 8. This problem no longer occurs in Internet Explorer 8."
lol that's what they propose as a solution :) nice
thanx anyways it helps

Comment: That's what they offer as a solution to users.  If you scroll down there is info for developers to fix the problem on the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2 :**If that the case Check here :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956196

You must indeed modify the `ieframe.dll.mui` file but not with a simple text editor. You need a ressource editor that can open library files and do the modifications in a "cleaner" way.

Start by making a copy of the original file in case you mess things up and then open the library with your ressource editor.
Once inside ieframe.dll.mui you must open the "23" sub-key and there you will see all the various ressources that can be modified. The messages you are looking to change is `DNSERROR.HTM.` Just copy/paste the proper HTML message you want and recompile/save the library. There is also `DNSERRORDIAGOFF.HTM and DNSERRORDIAGOFF_WEBOC.HTM` whose purpose I'm not certain of but I changed them as well just in case.

Please note that you may find multiple instances of the ieframe.dll.mui file on your system `(in system32/dllcache and system32/en-US among others)` you'll want to change these as well.

Source :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/ccb51696-6d0e-4669-9e79-19597b4cf40f

Comment: Actually I want my website to be shown on IE not modify the DNSERROR.HTM pas!! I wanna understand why it's not shown under IE

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956196